# Blockchain representation

Tags: java, blockchain

I am not able to understand the hashcode() part of the given code snippets.

I have tried searching about it but I am not able to figure it out.

```
    this.hash  = Arrays.hashCode(new Integer[]{data.hashCode(), previousHash});
```

Comment: The new hash is a hash of the data's hash combined with the previous hash.

Comment: Thats the same as `this.hash = 31 * (31 + data.hashCode()) + previousHash;`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays-class implements a set of ready made and robust methods for calculating hash codes for arrays of different types. This example calls `Arrays.hashCode(int[])`.

Essentially, this is just a way for creating a hash code from two existing hash codes (`data.hashCode()` and `previousHash`).